# What's this extra bytes?

Tags: executable, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I'm studying the PE (Portable Executable) format, but I saw a difference between C++ programs compiled with MinGW and MSVC:

[image]

It's some extra bytes after 'This program cannot be run in DOS mode' and before the 'PE' magic signature.
Anyone know what this is and why there's the 'Rich' word?

Comment: look [this](http://bytepointer.com/articles/the_microsoft_rich_header.htm) or [this](http://ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the "Rich header". It was added by Microsoft's link.exe (notice the text "Rich" at the end of the block). It's a structure in PE files between the DOS Header and the NT Header (between DOS stub and PE Header). It contains version information of linked libraries and the linkers versions.

**Further reading:**

- [The Undocumented Microsoft "Rich" Header](http://bytepointer.com/articles/the_microsoft_rich_header.htm)
- [Microsoft's Rich Signature (undocumented)](http://www.ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm)
- [Rich Header](https://trendystephen.blogspot.co.il/2008/01/rich-header.html)